# Is modus tollens applicable when a premise contains additional information

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I have something similar to the below:

\begin{align}
&1. \ p \to q \\
&2. \ \lnot q \land \lnot s \\ 
&\text{c} \colon \, \lnot p
\end{align}

Is this still equivalent to *modus tollens* since the 2nd premise can only be true if $\lnot q$ is true, and will be false if not? I am not really sure how to treat the $s$ variable seeing as it is not included in the conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is valid, but it would be clearer to describe it as being two steps:

1. From $\neg q \land \neg s$ conclude $\neg q$.
2. From $\neg q$ and $p\to q$ conclude $\neg p$.

Comment: Thanks for that. So `~s` has no effect on the statement so we can just conclude `~p` from it?

Comment: @MattHough: That's how the $\land$ connective works: From $a\land b$ you can conclude $a$; from $a\land b$ you can also conclude $b$; from $a$ and $b$ you can conclude $a\land b$. The particular system you work in may have names and/or slight variants for those rules.

Comment: Ok thank you. Yeah I just realised that was a rule of inference.